# What is this style of layered lettering called?

Tags: terminology, style-identification, lettering

Basically what the title says. I just can't think of what to call this style in order to look up tutorials.

[image: This]

Answer (score 1):

Not asked, but Illustrator users can achieve something resembling with blending. It's not a style, but Illustrator's function to stack objects along a straight line or a curve and make the objects to get morphed and colored gradually from one version (=front object) to another (=to back object).

An example

[image]

1. Make three vesions of the same object. One colored with white stroke and two with no stroke, only white fill. Make the other white version smaller. It's for perspective.
2. Make the smaller white version fully transparent in the transparency panel. Place white versions apart, select them and apply Object > Blend > Make. Before applying, set blending options = 100 steps. You may need to reverse the blend direction to get the opaque version on top.
3. Insert colored background and place the colored object version on top.

The result is vector and it can be copied to Photoshop in as high resolution as needed.

If you need those alternating darker and lighter versions visible, you can use groups as the blended objects:

[image]

The number of the steps is reduced to 50 to make the steps visible.

Comment: I don't know why someone would downvote this excellent answer. Ah well, never mind, I upvoted it!

Comment: @BillyKerr at least this wasn't a tutorial on demand. Maybe tutorials without demand are even worse.

Answer (score 0):

I found some results as **Sandwich 3d Extrusion**

[image: Sandwich 3d Extrusion]

Downloading the base PSD here https://graphicburger.com/sandwich-3d-text-effect-3-angles/, it is easy to discover how it has been done and adapt it to the example of the question.

[image: 3d]

Comment: I got a different result searching for sandwich 3D... :)

Comment: [You have omitted **Extrusion**](https://www.google.es/search?q=sandwich+3d+extrusion&rlz=1C5MACD_enFR506FR507&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOqr2Wm43eAhUsyIUKHZCSDcQQ_AUIDigB&biw=1429&bih=1143)

Comment: I don't think this looks anything like what the OP has asked for. Sorry Danielillo.

Comment: That's why I put the second paragraph in the answer

Comment: I think "3D extrusion" is more correct than "sandwhiched 3D extrusion" because a sandwhich makes me think of segmented parts, of which the example in the question has infinite